5 Pin Equivalent of MT-30 Connector
Normally I connect 2 different harnesses with 3 wires together with MT-30 connector, but I need to add 2 more wires and increase the number of wires to 5. I am looking for a 5 pin equivalent of the MT-30. The connectors I come across are usually automotive connectors and they are very expensive.
MT-30 Connector Link
I want to connect two harnesses containing five wires to each other with a connector pair (female-male). Is there a connector you can recommend for this?
If the connector can withstand up to 24VDC 4A, it is enough for me.
Thank you for your time.

This question will likely be closed as specific product recommendations are not allowed here but 4+ circuits at that current is getting out of the realm of cheap and accessible hobbyist-grade parts and into professional parts. Not to say that they'll be impossible to find, just that they won't be $1 on Amazon and you'll have to weed out all the $100 industrial and $1000 mil-spec parts. Start looking on the major electronics parts distributors for your region and filter aggressively. Welcome to the world of connectors! Edit: for a connector family that might work, check out M12 connectors.

@vir I'm sorry if I misrepresented myself. I have been searching for a long time on sites such as digikey, mouser, farnell. I just couldn't access the type of connector I wanted, so I asked for advice. Cables normally do not even carry 2A. I am looking for a connector that can carry up to 4A for security purposes. Thank you for your advice. Yeah what a big world of connectors!


24VDC 4A

That requirement is not too hard and easily met by dozens of connector families. For example, consider the Molex Mini Fit series:
https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/mini-fit-connectors
https://www.digikey.com/short/d8q15j7q
That's a  crimp connector. If you prefer to solder wires, consider D-dub:
https://www.digikey.com/short/83qz20db
